# Breqn and xypic

Tags: xy-pic, breqn

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{
    A \ar[r]^f & B
}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

generates the following output:

[image: Wrong arrow labels]

As you can see, the label is not attached to the arrow, but rather to A. Is there a fix, or is breqn and xy simply not compatible.

Compiled with xelatex
(XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2014012222 (TeX Live 2013/Debian))

Comment: I don't think there is any sensible way for making `breqn` compatible with Xy-pic. The `breqn` package, besides breaking equations, has the habit of breaking also other packages. You may try `tikz-cd` instead of Xy-pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `breqn` is not yet stable (at least it does not have a version 1 yet). You might want to report that problem to https://github.com/wspr/breqn/issues

Here some quote from their documentation:

> As it pushes the envelope of what is possible within the context of
>   LaTeX2ε, the breqn package will tend to break other packages when used
>   in combination with them, or to fail itself, when there are any areas
>   of internal overlap; successful use may in some cases depend on
>   package loading order.

The last statement is not true for your case. In the meanwhile, you should not use this package or switch from `xy` to `tikz-cd` which I would recommend in general.

This could look like the following:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
    Your commutative diagramm goes here:
    \[\begin{tikzcd}A\ar{r}{f}&B\end{tikzcd}\]
    And your super long formula here:
    \begin{dmath}a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you cannot live without those two packages, you might generate your commutative diagrams externally (`standalone` class) and include them as PDF. Or you tell us, what features of `breqn` you actually do need. Maybe, one can take out that feature manually from the package implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the github page. I only recently discovered breqn, so many equations are `hand-broken'. And I already have a dozen or so diagrams in xy, so i'll drop breqn for now.